# Calling methods from objects stored in an arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, methods, arraylist

I was wondering why this isn't working. I looked at another post that suggested the method I used for calling methods from Objects stored in an array but it doesn't seem to be working. I should clarify. I am referring to the `printPurchases` and `totalCost` methods. More specifically how they don't seem to be allowing me to call from the `Purchase` object at index `i`, but instead appear to be calling from the `get(i)` part. It is highlighted in red in my eclipse application.

```
public class Customer {

    private String name, address;
    double total;
    private ArrayList purchases = new ArrayList();

    public Customer(String name, String address){
        this.address=address;
        this.name=name;
    }

    public void makePurchase(Purchase purchase){
        purchases.add(purchase);
    }

    public String printPurchases(){
        for(int i=0; i<purchases.size(); i++){
            return **name+"\t"+address+purchases.get(i).toString();**
        }
        return"";
    }

    public double totalCost(){
        total=0;
        for(int i=0; i<purchases.size(); i++){
            total = **total+purchases.get(i).getCost();**
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly "*isn't working*"?

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: when using the List interface, specify what object you are storing. in your case, add <Purchase> after ArrayList

Comment: return is missing in `public double totalCost(){...}`

Answer (score 1):

Your return statement should have a space in between `return` and `""`.

```
public String printPurchases(){
    for(int i=0; i<purchases.size(); i++){
        return name+"\t"+address+purchases.get(i).toString();
    }
    return "";
}
```

`public double totalCost()` is suppose to return a `double`. You aren't returning a `double`.

```
public double totalCost(){
    total=0;
    for(int i=0; i<purchases.size(); i++){
        total = total+purchases.get(i).getCost();
    }

    return total;
}
```

Also, as said in the comments, specify what the `ArrayList` is to be filled with, by using:

```
private ArrayList<Purchase> = new ArrayList<Purchase>();
```

Answer (score 1):

The type information, ie the attr and method of `Purchase` will be erased (upcast to `Object`, with no *self-defined* attr or method) when you stored them in a `ArrayList` with no *Generic* Type, try store them like this:

```
private ArrayList<Purchase> purchases = new ArrayList<>();
```